# How we can deserialize the nested json object into python model object at once?

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

When we `serialize python model object` to nested `json data` we can serialize it in django as foe example.

```
DataSerializer(data_list, many=True)
```

and output will like that.

```
[
    {"name":"user_1", "id":1}, 
    {"name":"user_2", "id":2}, 
    {"name":"user_3", "id":3},
    ... ...
]
```

Now I want to deserialize the list of `json object` to `python model object` at once.

As for example:

```
# the serializer class
class UserSerilizer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)


# Request model class.
class UserRequestModel:
    id = None
    name = None

    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.__dict__.update(dictionary)
```

And what I do.

```
# serialize the request data for param validation
user_serializer = UserSerilizer(data=request.data)

# update the user request model with validate data
user_data = UserRequestModel(user_serializer.validated_data)
```

That's why I can access the value `user_data.id` and `user_data.name` for the request body `{"name":"user_1", "id":1}`

But how can I do it for list of data at once like we serialize at once with passing parameter `DataSerializer(data_list, many=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just append `deserialize` method in your `Serializer` class

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, data, many=False):
        if many is False:
            return UserRequestModel(data)
        else:
            obj_list = []
            for d in data:
                obj_list.append(UserRequestModel(d))
            return obj_list
```

But I can not understand why you want to deserialize. I don't think this is recommended in django.